# When does socket.recv() raise an exception?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, blocking, recv

I'm using blocking sockets and I'm quite confused about recv() because I didn't find any decent documentation about it. The official one seems restricted to me. The other thing that is confusing me is that people on the internet(and also on this site) says that it doesn't raise any exception for blocking sockets, but it simply keeps waiting. If I brutally close the server it throws an Errno 10054(socket.error) instead.

Comment: it obviously cannot wait if the connection was terminated. and somehow it has to notify you about the event. no surprises here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it simply, `recv` will throw an exception whenever the underlying socket operation fail. The problem is that it depends on the OS you are on. Here I can guess that you are on Windows, because 10054 is a [Windows error code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for connection reset. Fortunately, when and why socket operations fail is roughly consistent between OSes (check the [Windows documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details), and python has a portable solution to identify errors :

```
import errno
...
if err == errno.ECONNRESET :
    print "connection reset"
```

Comment: So in which case does it return an empty string?

Comment: An when does it keep waiting?

Comment: @MarcoFazio I'm not 100% sure, but I think it waits until data is received, an error occur, or the connection is gracefully closed. And empty string should only be when the connection has been gracefully closed, but you should test it to be sure.

Comment: Thank you. If I close the socket with a shutdown() it returns an empty string.

Comment: I correct myself. For some reason it returned an empty string once, but now it doesn't work.

Comment: My fault. I was shutting down and closing the wrong socket. It works!