# python recv never throws an error

Tags: python, sockets, amazon-ec2

This is the sample socket at server side (taken from some website):

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = ''   # Symbolic name, meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 10001 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
print 'Socket created'

#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
    conn.send("Test Messag")

s.close()
```

This is the code at client side:

```
import socket
s=socket.socket()
s.connect((ipaddress,port))
s.setblocking(1)
import time
counter = 0
while True:
    print counter
    chunk = s.recv(11,socket.MSG_WAITALL)
    if not chunk:
        raise Exception('Socket error')
    print chunk
    time.sleep(1)
    counter += 1
```

The server side code runs on an amazon ec2 instance (based on the amazon linux ami)
When I terminate the instance I would expect that the recv method on the socket throws an error, but it does not. Whatever I do, it never throws an error. When I run the server side code in an ipython notebook and restart the kernel, the recv method unlocks and keeps returning empty strings (according to [When does socket.recv() raise an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27568995/when-does-socket-recv-raise-an-exception) this should be in the case of a clean shutdown), but no error is thrown.

What could be the cause of this, I really need to have it throw an exception so I can notify the rest of my code that the server went down in order to start a new one.

Comment: Would a try-except raise an error? From that link it said the error raising differs from OS to OS.

Comment: Do you mean to explicitly raise an error in the socket code? If so how and where do I  need to do that?

Comment: In place of your `if not chunk:` section.

Answer (score 1):

> When I terminate the instance I would expect that the recv method on the socket throws an error ...

When the server terminates it will do a clean shutdown of the socket, so you will get no exception on the client side. To get what you want you would have to implement some kind of shutdown message inside your application. Then you can distinguish a proper shutdown (with an explicit shutdown message) from just a socket close.

Comment: Ok I was afraid for that, but I hoped to see the empty strings in case of a clean shutdown, but I don't see those either. The problem I'm actually having is with Pyro, so given your suggestion I should actually look at the server side code of Pyro instad of the client side and somehow make it send a proper shutdown message (which it does not seem to do anymore).

Answer (score 0):

You are making only one tcp connection. You have to make multiple request.

```
import socket
import time
counter = 0
while True:
    print counter
    s=socket.socket()
    try:
        s.connect((ipaddress,port))
        s.setblocking(1)
        chunk = s.recv(11,socket.MSG_WAITALL)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        break
    print chunk
    time.sleep(1)
    counter += 1
```